# stop setInterval only works one time, why?

Tags: javascript

I need some help, stop button invoke clearInterval() and only works one time, whats wrong in the code?

```js
var start = document.querySelector("#start");
var stop = document.querySelector("#stop");

window.addEventListener('load', () => {

  function intervalo() {
    var tiempo = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("Set interval ejecutado");
  }, 1500);
    return tiempo;
  }

  var tiempo = intervalo();
  
  stop.addEventListener("click", function() {   
    clearInterval(tiempo);
  });

  start.addEventListener("click", function() {
    intervalo();
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="stop"> stop! </button>
<button id="start"> start! </button>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `tiempo = intervalo();` instead of  `intervalo();` in `start.addEventListener("click", function() { .... });`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like setInterval is being called numerous times and therefor causing multiple timers to occur simultaneously; a cleaner version would be:

```js
let tiempo; 

const start = () => {
  console.log("starting...")
  if(!tiempo) {
    tiempo = setInterval(
      ()=> {console.log("interval")}
    , 1000)  
  }
}

const stop = () => {
  console.log("stopped")
  clearInterval(tiempo);
  tiempo = null; 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="stop()"id="stop"> stop! </button>
<button onclick="start()" id="start"> start! </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you notice that  `var tiempo = setInterval(function() {..})` was declare inside `function intervalo()` ? So **its scope** is in `intervalo` function.

But another `var tiempo = intervalo()` is declare outside intervalo, two variables `tiemp` are different, that's why `clearInterval(tiempo);` doesn't work.

Why first time does it work? Because when DOM was loaded and emit event `load` once, inside that function you set  `var tiempo = intervalo()`, and it was set one time only until you clear it. Next time clicking on `start` : outside `tiempo` wasn't set to anything.

The "fix" is simple: declare tiemp on the top of `load` callback, then set **it** equal intervalId return from `setInterval`.

```
var start = document.querySelector("#start");
var stop = document.querySelector("#stop");

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  var tiempo;
  function intervalo() {
    //tiempo was declared in this function's closure
    tiempo = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("Set interval ejecutado");
  }, 1500);
  }

  
  stop.addEventListener("click", function() {   
    //tiempo was declared in this function's closure
    clearInterval(tiempo);
  });

  start.addEventListener("click", function() {
    intervalo();
  });
});
```

p/s: please read more about `scope` in javascript, especially `closure`.

Answer (score 1):

your variable name is very confusing and you override previous setInterval `id` with newer one every time; so I suggest use a more clear naming structure to avoid such scenario;

```js
var start = document.querySelector("#start");
var stop = document.querySelector("#stop");
var intervalRefId;
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

  function intervalo() {
    return setInterval(function() {
      console.log("Set interval ejecutado");
    }, 1500);
  }

  intervalRefId = intervalo();
  
  stop.addEventListener("click", function() {   
    clearInterval(intervalRefId);
  });

  start.addEventListener("click", function() {
    intervalRefId = intervalo();
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="stop"> stop! </button>
<button id="start"> start! </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you set one time your variable `tiempo` you must set it again with your interval function

```js
var start = document.querySelector("#start");
var stop = document.querySelector("#stop");

window.addEventListener('load', () => {

  function intervalo() {
    return setInterval(function() {
       console.log("Set interval ejecutado");
    }, 1500);
  }
  var timer = true;
  var tiempo = intervalo();
  
  stop.addEventListener("click", function() {   
    clearInterval(tiempo);
    timer = false;
  });

  start.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(timer == false) {
       tiempo = intervalo();
       timer = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="stop"> stop! </button>
<button id="start"> start! </button>
```